# Solution for Could not find method maven()

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle Project sync Failed

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
        jcenter()
                   }
                   dependencies {`


classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    maven {
        url 'http://conjars.org/repo/'
        name 'Google'
        }
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

  }
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
        }
}
}

   task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

Please help me to solve this error and sync my gradle

Error Message :

> Could not find method maven() for arguments [build_c9dzq9rre1sc1dq0winaq8sc0$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure4@33323af1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Replace that with this :

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**And be sure about your internet connection**

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and after spending a couple of days luckily I figured out the solution.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://packages.confluent.io/maven"
        }
    }
}
```

And then add your dependency in dependencies{}.